# É possível estudar-se "biologia"?

Tags: gramática

Tive professores que diziam: Logia, é: Estudo de algo; lógica.

Duvido então, qual seja correta forma de se dizer. É possível estudar biologia? Ou, seria redundância dizer-se que se estuda um estudo?

Afinal, o que se estuda: "Biologia" ou "bio"?

Answer (score 10):

Certamente se pode estudar ([sentidos 1. e 2. do Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/estudar), respetivamente *aplicar o raciocínio, a percepção, a memória etc. para aprender* e *frequentar curso ou ser estudante (de)*) uma dada ciência ou disciplina. E a *biologia* é a «ciência que estuda os seres vivos e as suas leis orgânicas» ([Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/estudar)). Portanto, não há nenhuma razão para evitar *estudar biologia* (repara que *estuda* em «ciência que estuda» não é o mesmo predicado que *estudar* nos sentidos mencionados antes; nas definições do Aulete que referi, o argumento externo tem de ter o traço [+humano]; «ciência que estuda» significa «ciência dedicada aos estudos (de)»).

E isto é o fim da análise. A etimologia de uma palavra não determina o seu significado na atualidade (vê [*falácia etimológica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy)). Neste caso, *biologia* não é o mero ato de estudar os seres vivos; é a ciência/disciplina que se dedica a esses estudos.

Comment: nada impede de estudar um estudo